Failed to quote or execute swaps via universal router or v3 quoter
I am trying to do swaps via a js script, without using any uniswap sdk. I am currently trying to get a quoate via v3quoter, and i stumble across the same error that I get when I try to do swaps via execute, this is the piece of code that I am using:
async function logBalanceWorthAcrossPools() {
const adjustedBalance = parseFloat(balance) / (10 ** decimals);
const wethAddress = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(WETH);
const tiers = [500, 3000, 10000];

for (const tier of tiers) {
    try {
        console.log(`Tier: ${tier / 10000}%`);
        console.log(`Token Address: ${tokenAddress}, WETH Address: ${wethAddress}, Tier: ${tier}`);

        // Check if pool exists
        const poolExists = await checkPoolExists(tokenAddress, wethAddress, tier);
        if (!poolExists) {
            console.warn(`No pool found for tier ${tier / 10000}%. Skipping.`);
            continue;
        }

        // Scale balance for decimals
        const scaledBalance = BigInt(balance) * BigInt(10 ** decimals);
        console.log('Scaled balance ', scaledBalance)
        console.log('Balance ', balance)
        const amountOut = await uniswapV3Quoter.methods.quoteExactInputSingle(
            tokenAddress,
            wethAddress,
            tier,
            balance,
            0,
        ).call();

        const wethEquivalent = web3.utils.fromWei(amountOut, 'ether');
        console.log(`V3 Balance: ${adjustedBalance.toFixed(3)} ${tokenName}, Tier: ${tier / 10000}%, ~${parseFloat(wethEquivalent).toFixed(3)} WETH`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to quote for tier ${tier / 10000}%:`, error.message || error);
        if (error.data) {
            console.error('Reverted data:', web3.utils.hexToAscii(error.data));
        }
    }
}

}
And this is my output all the time:
Tier: 0.05%
Token Address: 0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984, WETH Address: 0xfFf9976782d46CC05630D1f6eBAb18b2324d6B14, Tier: 500
Pool address:  0x224Cc4e5b50036108C1d862442365054600c260C
Scaled balance  314513551084733000000000000000000n
Balance  314513551084733n
Failed to quote for tier 0.05%: Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract
Tier: 0.3%
Token Address: 0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984, WETH Address: 0xfFf9976782d46CC05630D1f6eBAb18b2324d6B14, Tier: 3000
Pool address:  0x287B0e934ed0439E2a7b1d5F0FC25eA2c24b64f7
Scaled balance  314513551084733000000000000000000n
Balance  314513551084733n
Failed to quote for tier 0.3%: Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract
Tier: 1%
Token Address: 0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984, WETH Address: 0xfFf9976782d46CC05630D1f6eBAb18b2324d6B14, Tier: 10000
Pool address:  0x51aDC79e7760aC5317a0d05e7a64c4f9cB2d4369
Scaled balance  314513551084733000000000000000000n
Balance  314513551084733n
Failed to quote for tier 1%: Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract
What am I missing as I think that it might be the same issue that I have when swapping.
